# Flutter camera issue in android version 13

Tags: flutter, android-camera, android-13

In Android 13 we are facing the below issue we are using this third-party camera plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/camera), I would really appreciate the help to solve the issue, Do we need to make some changes in our Android version?

```
E/flutter (14764): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: CameraException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.EncoderProfiles$VideoProfile.getWidth()' on a null object reference)
E/flutter (14764): #0      AndroidCamera.createCamera (package:camera_android/src/android_camera.dart:112:7)
E/flutter (14764): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (14764): #1      CameraController.initialize (package:camera/src/camera_controller.dart:291:19)
E/flutter (14764): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the step i followed, It's worked for me

1. Flutter upgrade 3.3.8 to 3.7.10(7-4-2023)
2. flutter pub cache clean
3. dart version number changed in pubsec.yaml (2.16 to 2.18)
4. flutter pub get
5. It's worked for me
6. Tested with samsung galaxy A13 and vivo v27 pro.
7. camera plugin version : 0.10.1

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known issue that is being tracked here:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109769
some people came with a solution ( that I haven't tried ) but as of the current state the issue is still not fixed in the latest package version